# Python functions return 1 when there is an exception

Tags: python, exception, return

Could you please explain why does the followin function return "1" when there is an exception? What is the purpose of returning "1"?

```
def initialize():
    """
    Starting point for the program.
    """
    try:
        go = Car()
        print "Instance of Car created"
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        return 1
```

Comment: Because the designer thought that returning "1" in case of KeyboardInterrupt was a good idea...

Comment: Without more context, your guess is as good as ours. Please provide more information about the general program this snippet is embedded in.

Comment: Ok, I thought it was a common python concept, returning "1" when there is an exception.

Comment: What is the context that `initialize` is called?  It claims to be the "Starting point for the program" -- is a call made from `__main__` that returns the return code of this function?

Comment: Actually after "go" is created, there is another statement, which calls a method of Car class, and that does the main job. But I was confused why the initialize function returns 1 when there is an exception. When I hit Ctrl+C there is a KeyboardInterrupt, right? And the program exits? So why does initialize() return 1?

Comment: "So why does initialize() return 1?" The simple answer is because it was written that way. Why was it written that way? As @li.davidm said, your guess is as good as ours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a fairly common idiom in C to return a non-zero value in case of an error.

My hunch here is that the person who created this function was used to programming in C and unfamiliar with exception handling. It's impossible to tell without a larger code sample, but if I'm right, then there is probably some sort of error handling present where this function is called in the case that this function returns 1, or a non-zero value.

If this is the case, a more proper way to use the exception would be to either use `raise` to pass the exception upward to be handled else where, or handle the exception right there in the function.

Comment: KeyboardInterrupt occurs when I hit Ctrl+C, right? Creating an instance of Car class should take only a few miliseconds, so why do you think they inserted a KeyboardInterrupt exception here? Do they think that the user may hit Ctrl+C in those miliseconds?

Comment: @alwbtc: I couldn't tell you how long it would take without seeing the code. It may be that while the Car class was being built there was a bug that made the program get stuck in an infinite loop or something similar. This may have been put in place as a debugging tool.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion there's no need to do this, only if the Car() constructor takes too long and you want to deal with it once `initialize()` returns.